# How to display current navbar state in AngularJS 1?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've had a frustrating time using UI-Router in AngularJS 1. When the page loads, I want the navbar image to reflect the current state: ie, if the user is on the home page, the "Home" navbar image should be highlighted blue (while the rest are grey); if the user clicks "About" & the state changes to "About", the navbar image for "About" should be highlighted blue while the rest remain grey, etc.

I have grey images & blue images stored in objs within my controller. I am watching for `$state` changes in the same controller. I've been facing a few hurdles in the way of getting this to work:

- If I `console.log($state.current)` within the `init()` function (which runs upon controller initialization via `ng-init`), it's telling me the current state is undefined. Thus, when the page first loads, none of the navbar images are blue (the "Home" image should be blue if the page the user is on is "Home").
- If `console.log(newVal)` within my `$scope.$watch`, I find that when the state changes the app does register this. However, if I try adding `ng-click="init()"` to one of my `<a>` tags, the `makeCurrentStateBlue()` function will register the state AT THE TIME OF THE CLICK instead of the state which actually loads after the user clicks the navbar button, making this solution useless.

I just need my navbar to substitute in one blue image based on the current state. Help!

Here is my navbar controller:

```
app.controller("NavCtrl", ['$scope', '$state',
  function($scope, $state) {

    $scope.init = function(){
      var srcs = angular.copy($scope.greys);
      srcs = $scope.makeCurrentStateBlue(srcs);
      $scope.imgsrcs = srcs;
    }

    $scope.imgsrcs = {};

    $scope.greys = {
      "home": "assets/navbar/grey1.jpg",
      "inventory": "assets/navbar/grey2.jpg",
      "about": "assets/navbar/grey3.jpg",
      "contact": "assets/navbar/grey4.jpg",
      "vendors": "assets/navbar/grey5.jpg"
    };

    $scope.blues = {
      "home": "assets/navbar/blue1.jpg",
      "inventory": "assets/navbar/blue2.jpg",
      "about": "assets/navbar/blue3.jpg",
      "contact": "assets/navbar/blue4.jpg",
      "vendors": "assets/navbar/blue5.jpg"
    };

    $scope.makeCurrentStateBlue = function(srcs){
      srcs[$scope.currentState] = $scope.blues[$scope.currentState];
      return srcs
    }

    $scope.$watch(function(){
      return $state.$current.name
    }, function(newVal, oldVal){
      $scope.currentState = newVal;
    });

}]);
```

Here is the relevant navbar HTML:

```
<a ui-sref="home">
    <img name="setup_r2_c1" ng-src="{{imgsrcs['home']}}" />
</a>

<a ui-sref="inventory">
    <img name="setup_r2_c2" ng-src="{{imgsrcs['inventory']}}" />
</a>

<a ui-sref="about">
    <img name="setup_r2_c3" ng-src="{{imgsrcs['about']}}" />
</a>

<a ui-sref="contact">
    <img name="setup_r2_c4" ng-src="{{imgsrcs['contact']}}" />
</a>

<a ui-sref="vendors">
    <img name="setup_r2_c7" ng-src="{{imgsrcs['vendors']}}" />
</a>
```